# Using database other than DynamoDB with iot-core

Tags: aws-iot-core

I'm just getting started on iot and note that iot-core uses DynamoDB. That's not going to work for me (no table joins, no stored procs etc.). Is it possible to use a different DB? I usually use Postgres but appreciate it may not be the quickest for a lot of inserts. What do others use?

Comment: what's the use case? What are you going to store in the DB?

Comment: Data from various types of building sensor, but from many users/companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IoT use case and telemetry data storage, I'd suggest to use [AWS Timestream](https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/). When data is sent to AWS IoT Core, you can use an [IoT Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rules.html) to forward data to [Kinesis Data Stream](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/) (useful here for decoupling as well as doing batch processing from downstream pipeline). [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) can be used to pull data from Kinesis Data Stream, enrich the data if needed (like adding building, users, company information) before storing the data into Timestream. You can then use [Grafana to visualize the data from Timestream](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-timestream-datasource/).

Comment: That all sounds sensible - I'm old school so not used to the SaaS type approach. I'll do some reading, thanks very much.